# User interaction on a page with tipsy

Tags: javascript, jquery, tipsy

Is there a way I can trace what the user does on the page. Mainly I want to do the following thing: User opens a page, if he does not click anywhere on that page to show a tooltip (i'm using tipsy) guiding him which parts are clickable.

So far I've tried several stuffs:

1. I have set tipsy to show manually: `trigger`:`manual`;
2. I made a variable that equals `false` until the user clicks those
   **clickable** items (divs and images)
3. If the variable is false, show the tooltip (*tipsy*).

But I'm missing something because this doesn't work. Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var userClick = false;

    function showTooltips() {
        $(document).ready(function()) {
            if(userClick === false)
                $('.nickname .pseudo-white').tipsy('show');
    }

    setTimeout(showTooltips(), 5000);
});
```

Comment: Could you post the rest of your code? I am curious as to the use case for this type of showing tooltips if the user does not click on anything for a certain amount of time. Thanks.

Comment: Here you can find a demo of the whole page: http://fakeheal.eu/new/ The main idea is if the user cannot understand the purpose of the site, to be guided through-out it. :)

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. I think I will look into using this technique for part of a project I am working on.

Comment: You can take a look at http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin it's more specific for "guiding users in your site", but I was after something more lightweight :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting rid of the extra call to $(document).ready, and pass the function name to setTimeout rather than calling it with ()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var userClick = false;

    function showTooltips() {
            if(userClick === false)
                $('.nickname .pseudo-white').tipsy('show');
    }

    setTimeout(showTooltips, 5000);
});
```